# Possible Unhandled Rejection in Expo MediaLibrary

Tags: react-native, promise, expo, media-library

I'm trying to fetch the albums in my media library via [Expo MediaLibrary SDK](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/media-library#expomedialibrarygetalbumsasync)

I'm trying to resolve the promise to get the all the album names, ids etc through the function Expo.MediaLibrary.getAlbumsAsync() which gets an array.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  Button,
  Clipboard,
  Image,
  Share,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  Alert,
} from 'react-native';
import Expo, { MediaLibrary, Permissions, Constants, ImagePicker, registerRootComponent } from 'expo';

export default class ChoosePhotos extends React.Component {
  state = {
    image: null,
    uploading: false,
  };

  //Get Permission and get Albums list

   async componentDidMount(){
     this.getAlbum();
  }

  getAlbum = async () => {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);

    if(status !== 'granted'){
      this.setState({ cameraRollPerm: false });

      Alert.alert(
        '',
        'Please grant permissions to access your media library to continue.',
        [
         /*  {text: 'Ask me later', onPress: () => console.log('Ask me later pressed')},
          {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel'}, */
          {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
        ],
        { cancelable: false }
      );
    }

    let albumList = await MediaLibrary.getAlbumsAsync()
      .then(albumArray => { console.log(albumArray) })
      .catch(() => { console.log("failed to fetch albums.") });

  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.image)
    let { image } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 20,
            marginBottom: 20,
            textAlign: 'center',
            marginHorizontal: 15,
          }}>
          Example: Upload ImagePicker result
        </Text>

        <Button
          onPress={this._pickImage}
          title="Pick an image from camera roll"
        />

        <Button onPress={this._takePhoto} title="Take a photo" />

        <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  _takePhoto = async () => {
    let pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
    });

    this.props.navigation.navigate('SizeSelectionScreen', {imageLink: pickerResult.uri});
  };

  _pickImage = async () => {
    let pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
    });
    this.props.navigation.navigate('SizeSelectionScreen', {imageLink: pickerResult.uri});
  }; 
}
```

I'm getting the same old Promise rejection error even I've handled it properly via catch and if the promise is not handled correctly, does it means I'm not getting my media library albums details?

Here is the error:

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5G88T.png)

Comment: please follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've changed the question.